# Threading over a parameter list and joining the results in Python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a list of arguments and a function that takes in an argument and returns some values based on that argument.
I want to parallelize this procedure. I also do not care in which order the results are returned, just all the values. Also, the argument list will be quite long (thousands), but the function is complicated and takes a few seconds to compute.

A minimal non-parallel version is:

```
def f(x): 
    return [x,x*x]

argument_list = list(range(1,8)) # random arguments
result_list = []
for a in argument_list:
    result_list += f(a)
print(result_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to stay close to your serial example; see the comments
in the source code for the details.
Note that in python a Global-Interpreter-Lock exists and tends
to make threaded computations less efficient than expected
(because all the threads are fighting for this global lock).
https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def parallelise(arg_list, arg_fnct, thread_count):
  import threading
  #
  # general purpose data structure to store anything
  class Record: pass
  #
  # the actual work performed by each thread
  def work(r):
    # divide equally the global data amongst threads
    amount=len(r.arg_list)
    begin=int(amount*r.thread_index/r.thread_count)
    end=min(amount, int(amount*(r.thread_index+1)/r.thread_count))
    # this thread will only work on its part of the global problem
    r.result=[]
    for i in range(begin, end):
      r.result+=arg_fnct(r.arg_list[i]) # call the original computation
  #
  # the set of data structures used by the threads (one each)
  thread_data=[None]*thread_count
  #
  # split the global work amongst many threads
  for idx in range(thread_count):
    r=Record()
    r.arg_list=arg_list           # provide global data of the problem
    r.thread_index=idx            # provide thread layout
    r.thread_count=thread_count   # provide thread layout
    r.thread=threading.Thread(target=work, args=(r,)) # prepare a thread
    r.thread.start()              # launch the thread
    thread_data[idx]=r            # remember this data structure
  #
  # collect the results
  result_list=[]
  for r in thread_data:
    r.thread.join()       # wait for the thread to finish its job
    result_list+=r.result # safely access its result
  return result_list

#~~~~ the original problem ~~~~

import sys

# the original computing function
def f(x):
  return [x, x*x]

# the global set of data to be processed
argument_list=list(range(1, 1000)) # random arguments

import multiprocessing
total_cpu_count=multiprocessing.cpu_count() # detect system properties
result_list=parallelise(argument_list, f, total_cpu_count)

sys.stdout.write('%s\n'%result_list) # everything is done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use multiprocessing module for parallelize this procedure. The advantage of this module is that you can use all or partial of your processor's cores depends on your needs. Threading module doesn't use more than one core parallelly because of global lock.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count


def f(x):
    return [x, x * x]


argument_list = list(range(1, 8))  # random arguments
result_list = []

for a in argument_list:
    result_list += f(a)

print(result_list)

# You can change the processes parameter according to your needs.

with Pool(processes=cpu_count()) as pool:
    result = pool.map(f, argument_list)

print(result)
```